# String-mapping-table in wikimedia-template

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

I would like to replace the contents of a variable with a value that can be found in a mapping-table.

For example:

Variable `priority` contains the value `3`, and should be replaced with the string `medium` according to the following table:

```
key   value
------------
1     none
2     low
3     medium
4     high
```

How do I accomplish this without having a giant mess of nested [replace](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:StringFunctions/de##replace:)-markup?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a switch statement from the same extension https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions#%23switch

Comment: Awesome, that's perfect!